# Place to declare "throws IOException" in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, ioexception, throws

I am new (and German so my English is not the best :D) 
I am working at a program, but I need to insert a `BufferedReader` & `FileReader`. 
I am working with GUI(graphical user interface) , and I know the mistake that I have to insert a `throws IOException` but I honestly do not know at which position. (because it is everywhere right next to `public static void main(String[] args)` but this does not exist in GUI)

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("pi.txt"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
String zeile1 = br.readLine(); 
char[] c = zeile1.toCharArray();
System.out.println(c[2]);
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Are you sure "pi.txt" is accessible by `FileReader`

Comment: yeah i am sure i looked about 5 times

Comment: You either need a try / catch as per NikNik's answer, or you can add a throws to the method that is calling the `BufferedReader`

Comment: Don't rethrow the exception, catch and handle it. Rethrowing it is an abdication of responsibility, pushing handling up to code that has less context for handling it. The idea of `try ... catch` is to let the program restor a valid state. Don't rethrow. And do use try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used GUI, but you can catch it with try-catch:

```
try{
  // your code
} catch (Exception e){

}
```

As suggested in comment, the best way is to catch specific exception and not the generic one. 
In your case, You need:

```
 FileReader fr;
    try {
      fr = new FileReader("pi.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
    //and

try {
  String zeile1 = br.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or

```
try {
  // your code
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
  // log
} catch (IOException e) {
  // log
}
```

Comment: ok yes. I tried that before but I always thought I need to write IOException in the catch()

Comment: You are welcome. If I was helpful, please upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: It is best not to just `catch (Exception ...)`. Always catch the specific checked exception(s) that might be thrown in the `try` block. This is a bad answer. I downvoted it.

Comment: I agree with you so I updated my answer. However I think that it is not bad answer. Maybe it need to be more precise. Thank you for you suggestion, I will upvote your comment

Comment: @LewBloch I tried to catch the specific exception and it did not work ? do I need to write *catch(Exception IOException)*?  or is IOException not the specific exception? or did I misunderstand it at all?

Comment: You can try to write catch(IOException e) -> your specific exception... catch(Exception e) is the generic one

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is a subtype of `IOException`, so one could put the IO code all in one `try` block with just the `catch (IOException...)`. And @Jana, `catch(Exception IOException)` is not how you do it. Read the Java Tutorial.

Comment: Why not remove those silly `TODO Auto-generated...` comments, hm?

Comment: ...and IOException is a subtype of Exception but as you said, always catch the specific exception :)

Comment: ok :D you two are very helpful. I tried both (catch(Exception e) but also catch(IOException e) ) both worked really good. I decided to take the second one because of your argument that I have to catch always the specific exception :D and yes I got that I do not have to write catch(Exception IOExxception) but thanks